# Drupal 7 - Change Back-end form UI based on check-box conditions

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am looking for following situation -Image Url - checkbox -if checked then we show an image upload button else we show an text box. Can anyone know to implement this in drupal backend can this be done with simple rules or we need an module for this.Thanks in advance

Comment: This may be of help: [Easiest method for conditional fields in a form](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/481/easiest-method-for-conditional-fields-in-a-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module Conditional fields
https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields 
It's easy to use, you create all fields than put dependencies.